# Access denied when trying to run Apache Solr

Tags: apache, solr, cmd

I am trying to start the Apache solr But it returns Access denied.

[image: attachment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change solr Directory permission

```
R – Read
W – Write
C – Change (write)
F – Full control

takeown /f <foldername>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run your command prompt as administrator
And then try to start solr

Comment: `~$ sudo /opt/solr/bin/solr start
WARNING: Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting.
         Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this check, start with argument '-force'`